# executing commands with pipes in c

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork

i have been trying to make a program that reads shell commands and executes them like

```
ls -l | sort > there.txt
```

However what i have done it doesn't seem to be executing the second command.
I am still new with c programming and i am not familiar with fork() and pipe() at all, so i wouldn't be surprised if what i have done has a ton of mistakes.
If anyone could help i would appreciate it.
Thank you in advance

Here is my code:

common.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void runThat(char* cmd1[], char* cmd2[]);
```

common.c :

```
#include "common.h"
void runThat(char* cmd1[], char *cmd2[]){
    pid_t pid, waitPid;
    int pipefd[2];
    int status;
    pipe(pipefd);
    pid = fork();

    if (pid<0){
        perror("Fork has failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid==0){
        dup2(pipefd[0],0);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        if (execvp(cmd1[0],cmd1)==-1){
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else{
        waitPid = wait(&status);
        if (waitPid == -1){
            perror("Waitpid failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        dup2(pipefd[1],1);
        close(pipefd[0]);


        if (execvp(cmd2[0],cmd2)==-1){
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is main:

```
#include "common.h"

#define BUFFER 300


int main(void){

    char * buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* BUFFER);
    unsigned int buffer_length;
    char* tkn;
    char * param[BUFFER];
    char * cmd1[BUFFER];
    char * cmd2[BUFFER];
    char *filename = NULL;
    char *output = NULL;
    int append = 0;
    int f1;
    int f2;
    int saved_stdin = dup(0);
    int saved_stdout = dup(1);

    printf("mysh4> ");

    while (1){  
        filename = NULL;
        output = NULL;
        memset(buffer,0,BUFFER);
        int input = getline(&buffer,&buffer_length,stdin);

        if (input==-1){
            printf("\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (input>BUFFER){
            printf("Error. Comand must not exceed %d characters.\n",BUFFER);
            exit(1);
        }

        switch(input){
            case 1:
                printf("mysh4> ");
                break;

            default:
                if ((strcmp(buffer,"exit\n")==0)||(strcmp(buffer,"terma\n")==0)||(strcmp(buffer,"end\n")==0)) {
                    printf("EXIT\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    int i =0; int j=0;
                    tkn = strtok(buffer," \t\n");
                    int NOP = 0;
                    while (tkn != NULL){
                        if(strcmp(tkn,"<")==0){
                            filename = tkn = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
                        }
                        else if(strcmp(tkn,">")==0){
                            output = tkn = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
                            append =0;
                        }
                        else if(strcmp(tkn,">>")==0){
                            output = tkn = strtok(NULL," \t\n");
                            append =1;
                        }
                        if(strcmp(tkn,"|")==0){
                            NOP++;
                            //param[i++] = NULL;    
                        }
                        //else
                            param[i++] = tkn; 
                        tkn = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");    
                    }
                    param[i] = NULL;
                    i=0; j=0;
                    while (param[i]!= NULL){
                        if (strcmp(param[i],"|")==0) break;
                        cmd1[i] = param[i];
                        i++;
                    }

                    cmd1[i] = NULL;

                    while (param[i]!=NULL){
                        if (strcmp(param[i],"|")==0) i++;
                        cmd2[j] = param[i];
                        j++; i++;
                    }
                    cmd2[j] = NULL;

                    i=0;
                    while (cmd1[i]!=NULL){
                        printf("cmd1 HAS:[%s]\n", cmd1[i++]);               // TO BE DELETED
                        if (cmd1[i]==NULL){
                            printf("cmd1 HAS:[NULL]\n");
                        }
                    }

                    i=0;
                    while (cmd2[i]!=NULL){
                        printf("cmd2 HAS:[%s]\n", cmd2[i++]);               // TO BE DELETED
                        if (cmd2[i]==NULL){
                            printf("cmd2 HAS:[NULL]\n");
                        }
                    }

                    printf("FILENAME :[%s]\n", filename);
                    printf("OUTPUT: [%s]\n", output);

                    if (filename){
                        f1 = open(filename,O_APPEND | O_RDONLY);
                        if(dup2(f1,0) < 0) {
                            perror("Dup2:Input failed."); exit(1);
                        }
                        close(f1);
                    }

                    if (output){
                        if(append == 0)
                            f2 = open(output,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);//TRUNC:ta sbhnei
                        else
                            f2 = open(output,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0777);
                        if(dup2(f2,1) < 0) {
                            perror("Dup2:Output failed."); exit(1);
                        }               
                        close(f2);
                    }

                    runThat(cmd1,cmd2);

                    dup2(saved_stdin,0);    
                    dup2(saved_stdout,1);   

                    printf("mysh4> ");
                    break;


                }//else

        }//switch
    }//while

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** After a lot of searching i found some posts of people that had similar issues as mine. Applying the suggested answers in my program i ended up with the function below. However, now when i type a command like "ls -l" it appears to be running twice

```
total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser  1553 Μάι  12 18:27 common.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser   313 Μάι  12 17:00 common.h
-rwxrwxr-x 1 csuser csuser 12204 Μάι  12 18:25 m
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser  2534 Μάι  12 18:00 mysh4.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser  7395 Μάι  12 12:44 p3090278-mysh4.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 csuser csuser    59 Μάι  12 17:46 that
-rwxrwxr-x 1 csuser csuser    22 Μάι  12 18:13 there
csuser@CSLAB2:~/Desktop$ total 40
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser  1553 Μάι  12 18:27 common.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser   313 Μάι  12 17:00 common.h
-rwxrwxr-x 1 csuser csuser 12204 Μάι  12 18:25 m
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser  2534 Μάι  12 18:00 mysh4.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 csuser csuser  7395 Μάι  12 12:44 p3090278-mysh4.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 csuser csuser    59 Μάι  12 17:46 that
-rwxrwxr-x 1 csuser csuser    22 Μάι  12 18:13 there
```

I also have edited my main class but i tested it and there was no issues at all, so something must be wrong again with the code below. It was supposed to be able to run for none or multiple pipes

```
void runThat(char *cmds[][MAX_PAR], int NOP){
    pid_t pid, waitPid;
    int status;
    int pipefd[2];
    int Num_Cmds = NOP +1;
    int r[Num_Cmds]; int w[Num_Cmds];
    char ** cmd;

    for (int i = 0; i < Num_Cmds; i++){
        r[i] = -1;
        w[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < NOP; j++){
        pipe(pipefd);
        r[j+1] = pipefd[0];
        w[j] = pipefd[1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Num_Cmds; i++){

        int h = 0;
        while (cmds[i][h]!= NULL){
            cmd[h] = cmds[i][h];
            printf("This [%s]\n", cmd[h]);
            h++;
        }
        cmd[h] = NULL;
        printf("This [%s]\n", cmd[h]);

        if (pid = fork() < 0){
            perror("Fork has failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(pid == 0){
            if (r[i] != -1){
                close(STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(r[i],STDIN_FILENO);
            }
            if (w[i] != -1){
                close(STDOUT_FILENO);
                dup2(w[i],STDOUT_FILENO);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < Num_Cmds; j++){
                close(w[j]);
                close(r[j]);
            }
            if (execvp(cmd[0], cmd)==-1){
                perror("Command Failed");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else{
            waitPid = wait(&status);
            if (waitPid == -1){
                perror("Waitpid failed");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(w[i]);
            if (i>0){
                close(r[i]);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) I don't see any code to open `there.txt` and set it as the standard output of the second process. (2) To construct a pipeline, you must start _all_ of the processes before you wait for _any_ of them; otherwise you may get deadlocked. (3) In general, for questions like this we want to see a _complete program_ that we can compile, run, and tinker with ourselves. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: It isn't your immediate problem, but you aren't closing enough file descriptors on the pipe in the first child. ***Rule of thumb:*** _if you use `dup()` or `dup2()` to redirect one end of a pipe to standard input or output, you should close **both** ends of the pipe._ There are a few circumstances where you might not need to do that, but they're few and far between. (Whether it will matter or not in this case is another discussion.) Also, there's no need to test whether `execvp()` fails.  If it returns, it failed.  (If it succeeds, a different process is running, never to return to this code.)

Comment: @zwol forgive me if this is a stupid question but how do i actually know that my processes are running or not. That is something i couldn't figure out so far...

Comment: @Sakis The moment `fork` succeeds, there are two processes, both of which are running.

Comment: @zwol do you know any good sources that i can read more about forks and pipes i found a few books about C but none of them had anything.

Comment: W. Richard Stevens' _[Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](https://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Programming-UNIX-Environment-3rd/dp/0321637739)_ is a good place to start.  It's not cheap, but any public or university library should either have a copy or be able to get one via inter-library loan.

Comment: You can also learn a great deal by reading the [GNU C Library Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) cover to cover, but some of the things in there only apply to "GNU systems", and it's not always obvious when that's the case.  (Most "distributions" of Linux qualify as "GNU systems", but Android doesn't, and neither does anything calling itself "SomethingBSD".)